# How about tags on the country of origin of aircraft?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Currently, Aviation SE has the tag [russia](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia), which is used for questions on the Russian Federation. However, questions on Russian aircraft often (mis)use this tag. Hence, I do believe it would be useful to have the tag [russian](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian).

For example, the [Sukhoi Su-30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-30) is a Russian aircraft, but it is operated not only by Russia, but also by Venezuela. Why use the tag [russia](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) when asking about aircraft designed and manufactured by Russia and then exported?

Suppose I want to search for questions on Russian fighters. Searching for `[russian] [fighter] is:question` would be more efficient than searching all tags starting with "mig" or "sukhoi".

Answer (score 6):

[soviet-union](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soviet-union) is currently used for aircraft that originated in the USSR (demonym: soviet), which adds a complication. For the purposes of an aviation Q&A site, I'm fine with having [soviet/soviet-union] as synonyms to [russia], but [others don't feel that way](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/62630/revisions).

[A tag is a topic being asked about](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), not a description of the things mentioned in a question. If my question is about the MiG-21, then it is not about all soviet/Russian fighters.

In my opinion the search function suffices.

Comment: Tags on SE are "flat". However, on at least one (non-SE) site, there's a hierarchy of tags with "parents" and "children". If SE were like that, then tags "MiG-29" and "Su-27" would have at least two parents, namely, "Russian Aircraft" and "Soviet Aircraft". Ideally, one would be able to retrieve all posts on a tag and also on its children. Unfortunately, that is not possible on SE. This question is an attempt to emulate parents and children within SE's limitations.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: If SE supported hierarchical tags, that would be a really nice feature.